# Arduino remote control - strange serial output

Tags: c, arduino, usb

I wrote a bit of code for my Arduino Nano 3.0 and I want to let a LED blink if I send a `1` via the USB hub. It works, but I don't understand the output made from the Nano and I hope somebody can explain it to me.

Here is my code:

```
#define LEDPIN 2
#include <SPI.h>

int Go = 0;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LEDPIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LEDPIN, LOW);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(LEDPIN, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(LEDPIN, LOW);

   while (Go != 1){
    Go = Serial.read();
    Serial.println(Go);         //a 1 will print 49, a 0 should print 48
    Go = (Go - '0');
    Serial.println(Go);
    }
}

void loop() {

  if (Serial.available() > 0){
    if ( Go == 1)
    {
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(LEDPIN, HIGH);
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(LEDPIN, LOW); 
     }
     else {}
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(LEDPIN, LOW);
    }
}
```

And this is the output:

```
-1  //this should be a 0 
-49 
.
.
.
49 //this is because of ASCII
1  // here is my 1 but the programm won't do the stuff in loop()
   // instead I have to send another 1 to get LED fun
```

At the very start of the programm I recieve a `-1` ??? Is this because of the USB connection or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: 1) we are, unfortunately, not a debugging service, 2) -1 from `Serial.read()` means there is no data available, you should use `Serial.available()` to check if data is available, see https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read

Comment: In the `setup` function you are reading the serial line without you wait for the data availability (`Serial.available()`).

Comment: I tried `Serial.available()` but in that case it just won't work. It wouldn't even print the first `Go`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is not doing what you think it is. Particularly, the loop code you wrote means:

1. if there is something in the serial buffer, then if Go is 1 blink
2. otherwise turn off the led.

In the setup, you clear the buffer. Consequently you will need another char in the queue to trigger the action.

From what you wrote, I think what you wanted to do is

1. if I wrote a 1 then blink
2. if I wrote a 0, then stop
3. if I wrote something else ... you did not specify, but I'll ignore this command

In order to do this, you'd want something like this:

```
#define LEDPIN 2
// #include <SPI.h> Not needed here

byte Go = 0; // Please, use the correct size for variables

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(LEDPIN, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(LEDPIN, LOW);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(LEDPIN, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(LEDPIN, LOW);

    Go = 0;
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available() > 0){
        // Something was received, so let's check it out
        byte tempGo = Serial.read();
        Serial.println(Go);         //a 1 will print 49, a 0 should print 48

        // this way if you did not receive any valid char nothing will change
        if (tempGo == '0')
            Go = 0;
        else if (tempGo == '1')
            Go = 1;

        Serial.println(Go);
    }

    if (Go){
        delay(1000);
        digitalWrite(LEDPIN, HIGH);
        delay(1000);
        digitalWrite(LEDPIN, LOW); 
    }else{
        digitalWrite(LEDPIN, LOW);
    }
}
```

Moreover the delays are a really bad habit; you don't want to wait for two seconds before seeing the correct output. In order to get rid of the delays, you can follow the example from the BlinkWithoutDelay example:

```
#define LEDPIN 2
// #include <SPI.h> Not needed here

byte Go = 0; // Please, use the correct size for variables
unsigned long prevMillis;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(LEDPIN, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(LEDPIN, LOW);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(LEDPIN, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(LEDPIN, LOW);

    Go = 0;
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available() > 0){
        // Something was received, so let's check it out
        byte tempGo = Serial.read();
        Serial.println(Go);         //a 1 will print 49, a 0 should print 48

        // this way if you did not receive any valid char nothing will change
        if (tempGo == '0')
            Go = 0;
        else if (tempGo == '1') {
            if (!Go) prevMillis = millis() - 1000; // This is in order to flash immediately
            Go = 1;
        }

        Serial.println(Go);
    }

    if (Go){
        while ((millis() - prevMillis) >= 1000){
            prevMillis += 1000;
            digitalWrite(LEDPIN, !digitalRead(LEDPIN));
        }
    }else{
        digitalWrite(LEDPIN, LOW);
    }
}
```

DISCLAIMER: this code is not tested; there may be some bugs inside

Comment: thank you! but can I ask you a question? why not delay? do they freeze the whole programm? 
I am new to Arduino progamming btw

Comment: @Tim that's exactly the reason. When you enter the delay function, you are allowed to exit only after that amount of time has passed (let's ignore interrupts). You can try it; you will notice that the program processes the command only after they have finished (so once every two seconds). In the second case, the program responds (almost) immediately, since it is continuously polling the serial buffer. delays are rarely useful, unless you explicitely want to block the program